# Quickly disappearing process bar - what process is it

Tags: mac, malware, sonoma

About a week ago I updated to Sonoma - since then periodically a process monitor appears on my screen and gets done in less than a second.

A gray backround, rounded corner process bar of some sort which is about 70% of screen width, centrally positioned on the screen, that draws a quick bar from nothing to 100% green and then disappears.

It is sort of too quick to get any information about what it is. So I have not been able to read what it says - although it does say something.

I would like to know what it is, and hopefully turn it off.

I wonder if it could be a form of spyware from my work, they mandate the updates to new OS etc.

Comment: There seems to be a spate of these recently - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466279/how-to-diagnose-a-dialog-box-that-flashes-up-unpredictably-at-irregular-interva for starters

Comment: Could it be the "verifying app" window? Does it happen when you launch an app?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so, should it happen whenever I start an app, whenever I start an app that hasn't been verified recently?

I just closed and restarted Krita and didn't get it, and I think I've been running FF developer for a while, and it happens when I'm running that. Opening new site doesn't affect it either.